# AngularJS weird behavior with html <select> tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-select

I am new AngularJS framework. I have few questions related to use of `<select>` tag in angularjs.

 Firstly, whenever I am putting the first value of the option in the  `<select>` tag, it shows an extra blank option in the drop down. Then, when I select any of the options in the dropdown, it disappears.
 Secondly, whenever I am keeping any of the options blank, then it behaves normally.

Why is it happening.?
Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Binding</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">

    <div>
        Search 1: <select ng-model="optval1" >
                  <option value="any">Any</option> 
                  <option value="name">Name</option>
                  <option value="city" selected>City</option>
                </select>
              <br>
        Selected Value={{optval1}}<br><br>
        Search 2: <select ng-model="optval2" >
                  <option value="">Any</option> 
                  <option value="Name">Name</option>
                  <option value="City">City</option>
      >          </select>
              <br>
        Selected Value={{optval2}}
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to load the initial value.

```
<select ng-model="optval1" ng-init="optval1='any'">
                  <option value="any">Any</option> 
                  <option value="name">Name</option>
                  <option value="city">City</option>

</select>
```

If you don't want to use initial value using `ng-init.`

**use ng-show/ng-if**.

```
<select ng-model="optval1">
    <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
    <option value="any">Any</option> 
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
</select>
```

You can also hard-coded style element to the first dropdown value.

For ex:

```
<select ng-model="optval1">
       <option style="display:none" value="">select</option>
       <option value="any">Any</option> 
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
</select>
```

Does the same thing like ng-if/ng-show.

Hope this solves your problem and informative as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you're providing incoherent, contradicting information to the framework. The select is bound to `optval`, so it's the value of `optval` that tells Angular which of the options must be selected (your selected attribute is completely useless, and once again, contradictory).

1. You're saying that the only possible values of `optval1` are `"any"`, `"name"` and `"city"`.
2. But the `optval` value is not any of those values.

So AngularJS has to do something to compensate, and it adds a blank option.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div>
        Search 1: <select  ng-model="optval1">
                  <option value="any">Any</option> 
                  <option value="name">Name</option>
                  <option value="city">City</option>
                </select>
              <br>
        Selected Value={{optval1}}<br><br>
        Search 2: <select ng-model="optval2" >
                  <option value="">Any</option> 
                  <option value="Name">Name</option>
                  <option value="City">City</option>
      >          </select>
              <br>
        Selected Value={{optval2}}
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>



<script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.optval1 = "city";

});

</script>
```

please find below code

Comment: ng-init should almost never be used. This is clearly specified in the documentation. Please don't encourage its usage. The controller should initialize variables. Not the view.

Comment: In that case we can assign the default value of ng-model="optval1" during controller load